# how to use _debounce when lodash is imported using import lodash from lodash

Tags: reactjs, lodash

how do I call _.debounce method when I have imported lodash using `import lodash from "lodash"` and not `import _ from 'lodash'`

Comment: lodash.debounce?

Comment: Just as you have it there. `_.debounce(func, [wait=0], [options={}])`

Comment: Made it worked. import lodash from "lodash"; const _ = lodash; _.debounce(myfunc, 500).